# Convert the dictionary with key and list of values to a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, matrix

How can I convert a dictionary like this {1: [0, 1, 2], 2:[3, 4, 5]} to a matrix [[1, 0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4, 5]]???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the dictionary, and append the key and values, which is a list to a bigger list.

```
dct =  {1: [0, 1, 2], 2:[3, 4, 5]}
lst = [[key]+value for key,value in dct.items()]
print(lst)
#[[1, 0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```